# Find a function f(u) such that the following ODE becomes exact.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm a bit puzzled with this question:

Find a function f(u) such that this function becomes exact:

$$\ f(x+y)+\ln(x)+(e^{x+y}+y^2)y'=0,$$ my initial thoughts were setting

$$\ P(x,y):= f(x+y)+\ln(x); Q(x,y):=e^{x+y}+y^2,$$

then$$\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial y}=f'(x+y)=e^{x+y}=\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x}, $$ ${}{}{}$

so $$\ f(x+y)=e^{x+y}, $$

Is this right? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: to show correct answer, thanks everyone!

Comment: What is an "exact" ODE?  Separable?

Comment: You should do $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ instead of the other way.

Comment: @KittyL Ah, silly me for not proofreading the question on here before submitting, made the necessary changes now. Is my method right now?

Comment: Not exactly, review your derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better, $\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial y}=f'(y+x)=e^{x+y}=\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$

$$f(x+y)=\int e^{x+y}dx+g(y)=$$

$$=e^{x+y}+g(y)$$

$$f(x+y)=\int e^{x+y} dy+h(x)=$$

$$=e^{x+y}+h(x)$$

$g(y)=0$, $h(x)=0$

$e^{x+y}+\ln(x)+(e^{x+y}+y^2)y'=0$

Comment: Ah yes, I see my initial mistake in the approach to this now. Thank you very much for clearing this up for me!